# Extra page inserted when using hyperref and table with lists

Tags: tables, hyperref, lists

Ok, I have compiled a MWE that I find very strange. There is an extra blank page and if I comment out the hyperref package the extra page disappears as well as if I remove one of the lists. I really don't want random empty pages popping up in my work, how do I remove it without removing the hyperref package?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside, openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \section{Vilka företeelser på internet är eTjänster?}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{9cm}|  }
        \hline
        Exempel på företeelse & Prövning mot de tre grundläggande egenskaperna\\
        \hline
        VR & \begin{enumerate}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Japp.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Japp.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Japp.
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        AR & \begin{enumerate}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Nix.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        Smart glasses & \begin{enumerate}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Japp.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
        Ljudturer & \begin{enumerate}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Ja om en lyssnar på distans.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `tabular`is taller than the height of the textblock. You should get a warning informing you about this: "Overfull \vbox (52.97647pt too high) ".

Comment: Just checked the logs and there is indeed such a bad box warning. How can the box be split over several pages?

Comment: Personally, I suggest trying to reduce the spacing around the `enumerate` list. The table should easily fit onto a single page without all that white space. If you nevertheless want to split your table over multiple pages, use `longtable` instead of `tabular`.

Comment: Great, thanks everyone, I'm going with longtable for now but I might switch to the space-reducing method later if I have time over

Comment: If you want to use `longtable`, please keep in mind that pagebreaks can only occur between table rows, not within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `enumitem` you can define your own `enumerate`-like environment specifically for the use in  tables. Spacing and indentation can of course be further customized. In the following example, I also used `tabularx` to make sure the table is as wide as the textwidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{article}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{NoHyper},
                  after=\end{NoHyper}\end{minipage}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \section{Vilka företeelser på internet är eTjänster?}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|X|}
        \hline
        Exempel på företeelse & Prövning mot de tre grundläggande egenskaperna\\
        \hline
        VR & \begin{tabenum}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Japp.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Japp.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Japp.
        \end{tabenum}\\
        \hline
        AR & \begin{tabenum}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Nix.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{tabenum}\\
        \hline
        Smart glasses & \begin{tabenum}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Japp.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{tabenum}\\
        \hline
        Ljudturer & \begin{tabenum}
            \item Tjänsteleverantören är en organisation: Japp.
            \item Tjänsten används över internet: Ja om en lyssnar på distans.
            \item Vi använder deras IT-system: Nix.
            
            Tjänsten är en e-tjänst: Nix.
        \end{tabenum}\\
        \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```