# Enumitem: why `hyperref` influence on style of new list style based on enumerate?

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, enumitem

Why `hyperref` influence on defining a style for new list which is based on enumerate?

In a case, when you need lists in tables is handy to define new list, something like is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}% <-- defined new list
    \setlist[tabenum]{nosep,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     label={\textbf{\arabic*.}},
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},    % <---
                     after=\end{minipage}                       % <---
                     }
    \newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
    \setlist[tabitem]{nosep,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     label=\textbullet,
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},    % <---
                     after=\end{minipage}                       % <---
                     }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
Column 1 Heading    & Column 2 Heading \\
    \hline
\begin{tabitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{tabitem}      &   \begin{tabenum}
                        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        \item More and more lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
                        \end{tabenum}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which gives expected result:

[image]

however, if in above WME I load `hyperref` package, the result is different, but only at `tabenum`:

[image]

Can be this considered as bug or I doing something wrong in definition of the `tabenum` list?

Comment: You can overcome this by adding the nohyper environment in your definition of the tabenum environment. See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578888/134144

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423014/2388

Comment: @leandriis, thank you very much for the link. Your solution works fine, if tables doesn't contain mix of `itemize` and `enumerate` based new lists. In my case the last item in `\tabitem` spill out of left border of column (or minipage).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you very much for information. Your and Heiko answer gives me some ideas how can i solve my problem. Actually, now I search how to determine height of `hyperref` marker. So far I estimated (by trial and error method) that is about `0.6\baselineskip`.

Comment: don't rely to much on this, I'm hopping that we can change the behaviour in some not to far feature and move the creation of the destination to a better place.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. Meanwhile I will stick by my estimation and considering it in `tabenum` definition.