# hyperref adds space above enumerate environment in longtabu environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabu

Look at this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, tabu, enumitem, geometry, lipsum, calc}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{l>{\compress}X}
Dummy &
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

And this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, tabu, enumitem, geometry, lipsum, calc, hyperref}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{l>{\compress}X}
Dummy &
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

And you can see the alignment issue. How to fix it? Removing the package isn't a solution, because I have to use it (of course, this is not what I am writing, this is just MWE that reproduces the problem.) Perhaps I am not much aware of what the `\compress` it doing behind the hood, so am having trouble dealing with this problem.

Comment: I will not debug something involving the tabu package. The tabu package is broken: see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there some alternative to `longtabu` then?

Comment: You could take a look at the `xltabular` package. It makes sure, tables can spread across multiple pages, while at the same time offering an `X` type column similar to `tabularx`.

Comment: An approach similar to the one in [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578888/134144)  should also be applicable to your table. Just replace `tabularx` with `xltabular`.

Comment: @leandriis Your approach is very promising. But this problem: `\begin{tabenum}\item Item one\item Item two\end{tabenum}
` this compiles to a list with the last item shifted to the right. How to make it look like a normal list?

Comment: @leandriis I am sorry I meant left in the previous comment.