# Dimension too large after recent longtable update

Tags: tables, errors, longtable, tabu, longtabu

After recent update of `longtable` package (2021.05.07) I am getting the error:

```
Dimension too large. \end{longtabu}
```

Log:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
=
l.10 \end{longtabu}
             
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{tabu}%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu}  {llX}
a & b & c\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I had an issue with `tabu` package today. Ulrike said it's broken. [ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600677/hyperref-adds-space-above-enumerate-environment-in-longtabu-environment#comment1506460_600677)

Comment: The problem is that `longtable` is actively maintained to fix issues; on the other hand, `tabu` has been buggy forever and unmaintained for several years.

Comment: `tabu` is frozen from 2019-01-11, and my error appeared recently, that's why I think there is also some problem with maintained `lontable` package.

Comment: Shall I wait for fix on `longtable` side? Or switch to some other package?

Comment: The problem is not longtable but tabu. And there is no maintainer in view to take it over and correct its incompabilities. So currently it is recommended not to use it.

Comment: Still dont understand why my code worked just fine with previous `longtable` versions (up to 4.16).  This particular error appeared only after recent update of `tools` (parent of `longtable`). Perhaps there is also a lot of problems with `tabu` but why my code worked fine one mouth ago? `tabu` has not changed for 2 years.

Comment: you probably also updated latex. tabu does lots of low-level tricks and every change in latex can make it fail in more places. Sorry but since years the advice is not to use this package, see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu.

Comment: @andc it worked with 4.14? that's sort of interesting 4.14 was a slightly large update (given that there hadn't been an update for 20 years, any update is "large") but 4.15 was small and 4.16 was tiny.

Comment: I just tried 4.14,4.15 and 4.16 and tabu fails with all of them which is more understandable 4.14 had some re-organisation to cope with floats appearing on the same page (when older versions would run off the bottom of the page in some cases)

Comment: I've rolled back parent container package `tool`  to previous version (56514) where `longtable` had version 4.12 and it works. `tool` container was updated 2021-06-01 and from that date my code doesn't work. I think I must switch to `xltabular`.

Comment: Ulrike found that tabu was relying on me using box1 and failds now I allocate a longtable-specific box (to avoid clashes with other packages....)  https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/issues/26

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tabu` is unmaintained but as a short term fix you can force an old version of longtable to load

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]%
\usepackage{tabu}%
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}  {llX}
a & b & c\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

The changes in `longtable` have been very minor and only addressing features that fairly obviously needed addressing, but apparently `tabu` was relying on an internal definition somewhere.

---

It turns out that specifically `tabu` is relying on `longtable` using the `\box1` scratch register and fails now `longtable` allocates a box for its internal use (a change made to avoid conflicts with other packages, you can't win...)  there is a patch at the tabu github

https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/issues/26

Answer (score 4):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. You can use `tblr` and `longtblr` environments with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table Caption},
]{llX[2,c]X[3,r]}
\hline
  a & b & c & d \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `tabularray` has substantially worse performance than `tabu`.

Comment: I was in the same case, and I've discover this package, which brings together a lot of features seamlessly : X columns, longtable, border and cell colors, ... A must !