# replace tabu code (longtabu) code with tabularray code (longtblr)

Tags: tabu, tabularray

I have been using tabu 10 years ago and it worked fine but the code is unusable since tabu has [bugs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600724/dimension-too-large-after-recent-longtable-update).

This is what my table looked like (from the old pdf)

[image]

And this is the tabu code used for this example

```
 { % start a group 
 \colorlet{tabledarkheadcolor}{black!60}
  % style  
  \small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
  % required if floatrow is loaded
  \IfDefined{floatsetup}{\floatsetup[longtable]{font={sf,small}}} 
  % the table
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth%
  {X[2,l]>{\ttfamily}X[2,l]X[2,l]}
\captionabove{Links to locations for configurations of the document layout}
\label{tab:doc:configurationlinks}
 \\
  \hline
  \taburowcolors 1{tabledarkheadcolor .. tabledarkheadcolor}
  \upshape
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Setting} &
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Option/Value}  &
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Location} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \upshape
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Setting} &
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Option/Value}  &
  \sffamily\textcolor{white}{Location} \\ \hline
\endhead
  \hline 
  \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{continued on next page \ldots}}
\endfoot
  \hline
\endlastfoot
%
\taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Options in file: \file{LaTeXTemplate.tex}} \\
\taburowcolors 2{tablebodycolor .. tablerowcolor}
%
paper size & paper=a4 & 
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
language   & english  & 
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
font size  & fontsize=11pt & 
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
color of hyperlinks & \bs{}UseDefinition\arg{Target}\arg{Web} &         
    Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
page layout in the pdf view & pdfpagelayout & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
%
\taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex}} \\
\taburowcolors 2{tablebodycolor .. tablerowcolor}
%
equation position & fleqn & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
quotation style   & german=quotes & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
citation style    & style=alphabetic & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
bibliography backend & backend=biber & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
%
\taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Settings and options in file: \file{preamble/style.tex}} \\
\taburowcolors 2{tablebodycolor .. tablerowcolor}
%
url font        & \cs{urlstyle}\arg{tt} &  
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:text]{StyleText} \\
threshold for \cs{blockquote} & \cs{SetBlockThreshold}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:quotes]{StyleQuotes} \\
numbering of figures & \cs{numberwithin}\arg{figure} & 
    Section:  \hyperref[sec:style:captions]{StyleCaptions} \\
paragraph skip or indentation & parskip=false &  
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:paragraph]{StyleParagraph} \\
line spacing    & \cs{onehalfspacing} &  
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:linespacing]{StyleLineSpacing} \\
size of text body   & DIV=11 & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
binding correction  & BCOR=10mm & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
single/two side layout & twoside=true & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
separate title page & titlepage=true & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:titlepage]{StyleTitlepage} \\
sections numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{secnumdepth}\arg{2} & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
headings size   & headings=small &  
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
chapter prefix  & headings=nochapterprefix & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
heading fonts   & \cs{setkomafont}\arg{sectioning} & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings:fonts]{StyleHeadingsFonts} \\
toc numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{tocdepth}\arg{3} & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
bibliography in TOC & bibliography=totoc & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
index in TOC    & index=nottotoc & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
LOF in TOC  & listof=notoc & 
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
%
\end{longtabu}
} % close the group
```

Now I started with a minimal example to replace this code by a `longtblr`, but it does not like like I want it to look like and I fail to define the `\endfirsthead`, `\endfoot`, `\endlastfoot`. I did not find out how to specify the row color of a multicolumn.
The head color is not used.

[image]

Here a minimal code that compiles but does not solve to replace the tabu code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\file[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash{}#1}\relax}
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}
\renewcommand\arg[1]{\{\texttt{#1}\}}
 
\begin{document}
 { % start a group 
    \colorlet{tabledarkheadcolor}{black!60}
    \colorlet{tablerowcolor}{black!20}
    \colorlet{tablebodycolor}{white}
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continued on next page \ldots}
    % style  
    \small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
        \begin{longtblr}[  
            caption = {Links to locations for configurations of the document layout},
            label = {tab:doc:configurationlinks},
            ]{
                colspec = {X[2,l]>{\ttfamily}X[2,l]X[2,l]},
                width = 1.0\textwidth,
                row{1}   = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily\upshape},
                row{odd} = {bg=tablerowcolor},              
            }
            \hline
            Setting &
            Option/Value &
            Location \\ \hline
            %\taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
            \SetCell[c=3]{l} Options in file: \file{LaTeXTemplate.tex} \\
            %
            paper size & paper=a4 & 
            option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
            language   & english  & 
            option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
            font size  & fontsize=11pt & 
            option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
            color of hyperlinks & \bs{}UseDefinition\arg{Target}\arg{Web} &         
            Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
            page layout in the pdf view & pdfpagelayout & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
%           \taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
            \SetCell[c=3]{l} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
            %
            equation position & fleqn & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
            quotation style   & german=quotes & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
            citation style    & style=alphabetic & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
            bibliography backend & backend=biber & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
            header and footer & automark,komastyle &
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
            backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
            %
%           \taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
            \SetCell[c=3]{l} 
            Settings and options in file: \file{preamble/style.tex} \\
            %
            url font        & \cs{urlstyle}\arg{tt} &  
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:text]{StyleText} \\
            threshold for \cs{blockquote} & \cs{SetBlockThreshold}\arg{2} &
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:quotes]{StyleQuotes} \\
            numbering of figures & \cs{numberwithin}\arg{figure} & 
            Section:  \hyperref[sec:style:captions]{StyleCaptions} \\
            paragraph skip or indentation & parskip=false &  
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:paragraph]{StyleParagraph} \\
            line spacing    & \cs{onehalfspacing} &  
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:linespacing]{StyleLineSpacing} \\
            size of text body   & DIV=11 & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
            binding correction  & BCOR=10mm & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
            single/two side layout & twoside=true & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
            separate title page & titlepage=true & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:titlepage]{StyleTitlepage} \\
            sections numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{secnumdepth}\arg{2} & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
            headings size   & headings=small &  
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
            chapter prefix  & headings=nochapterprefix & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
            heading fonts   & \cs{setkomafont}\arg{sectioning} & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings:fonts]{StyleHeadingsFonts} \\
            toc numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{tocdepth}\arg{3} & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
            bibliography in TOC & bibliography=totoc & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
            index in TOC    & index=nottotoc & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
            LOF in TOC  & listof=notoc & 
            Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
            %
        \end{longtblr}
    } % close the group
\end{document}
```

Comment: [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) has its own way to define what is going to appear in subsequent pages. Have a look at Chapter 4 in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)

Comment: I have read chapter 4 multiple times, but I do not see the solution. Basically I miss a full example like the one I have posted that explains the usage. I can not understand why the header has the wrong color and I have no example for headings in the middle of the tabular.

Comment: There are few things one need to be aware of when using `longtblr`, `tblr` or `talltblr`. I have edited my answer. Perhaps the comments in the text, comments in code, and ridiculous styles including header/footer content will clarify how `longtblr` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only changed a few things in your code and the table starts resembling your old PDF.  I think you could continue with this.

One remark, though, you should add more generic settings first and then add more specific changes afterwards. Otherwise, settings  might be lost, e.g. `row{1} ...` in your code is overwritten by `\row{odd} ...`.

I also added

```
rowhead = 1,
rowfoot = 0,
```

which instructs the table about how many head rows and last foots rows get repeated on first and other pages.

---

EDIT.
I have added a few things to the code with comments to clarify how `longtblr` works. There are a few important aspects

- `longtblr` consists of three parts: **head**, **body**, and **foot**, similar to `threeparttable`

  - both **head** and **foot** can have three prefixes: **first**, **middle** and **last** to alter these parts on specific pages
  - Both **head** and **foot** can be styled with fonts and colours using `\SetTblrStyle{}{}`
- `longtblr` works with templates that alter content of **head** and **foot**

  - elements are altered using combination of `\DeclareTblrTemplate{}{}{}` and `SetTblrTemplate{}{}`
  - every element from the Table 4.4 (see [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)) can be defined with respect to a custom template
  - other commands s.a. `\UseTblrTemplate{}{}` and `\ExpTblrTemplate{}{}` can use already defined templates inside definition of another template
- A combination templates can be shred across a document.

I think below is the most important part of my example

```latex
%%% Style for the table
% Decalre the template "crazy"
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}{
  \centering
  XXX:
  Crazy table:%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  :XXX%
  \par
}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{middlehead}{crazy}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{lasthead}{crazy}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}}
% Decalre the template "fancy"
\DeclareTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}{Continued on next page \ldots}
%%% Create a new theme with the template custom
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  % Use template fancy
  \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}
  % USe template custom
  \SetTblrTemplate{middlehead}{crazy}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lasthead}{crazy}
  \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{fg=red,font=\bfseries}
  \SetTblrStyle{middlehead,lasthead}{fg=black!30!green,font=\itshape}
  \SetTblrStyle{lasthead}{fg=blue}
  \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=red2}
  \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{font=\itshape}
}
```

It demonstrates how you declare new templates including specific elements, which in turn are set in a theme. I can see it might look a little too complex at first but I guess the main idea was that themes can share the same templates, which in large document may greatly reduce code and increase clarity.

The screenshots from my example

[image]

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand\file[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash{}#1}\relax}
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}
\renewcommand\arg[1]{\{\texttt{#1}\}}

\colorlet{tabledarkheadcolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{black!20}
\colorlet{tablebodycolor}{white}



%%% Style for the table
% Decalre the template "crazy"
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}{
  \centering
  XXX:
  Crazy table:%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  :XXX%
  \par
}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{middlehead}{crazy}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{lasthead}{crazy}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{crazy}}
% Decalre the template "fancy"
\DeclareTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}{Continued on next page \ldots}
%%% Create a new theme with the template custom
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  % Use template fancy
  \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}
  % USe template custom
  \SetTblrTemplate{middlehead}{crazy}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lasthead}{crazy}
  \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{fg=red,font=\bfseries}
  \SetTblrStyle{middlehead,lasthead}{fg=black!30!green,font=\itshape}
  \SetTblrStyle{lasthead}{fg=blue}
  \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=red2}
  \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{font=\itshape}
}


\begin{document}
\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
\begingroup
  \begin{longtblr}[
    theme = mytheme,
    caption = {Links to locations for configurations of the document layout},
    label = {tab:doc:configurationlinks},
  ]{
    colspec = {X[2,l]>{\ttfamily}X[2,l]X[2,l]},
    width = 1.0\textwidth,
    row{odd} = {bg=tablerowcolor!20},
    row{1}   = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily\upshape},
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 0,
  }
    \hline
    Setting &
    Option/Value &
    Location \\ \hline
    %\taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{LaTeXTemplate.tex} \\
    %
    paper size & paper=a4 &
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
    language   & english  &
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
    font size  & fontsize=11pt &
    option of \hyperref[sec:main:class]{\cs{documentclass}} \\
    color of hyperlinks & \bs{}UseDefinition\arg{Target}\arg{Web} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
    page layout in the pdf view & pdfpagelayout &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:preamble:configuration]{Configurations} \\
  %           \taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
    %
    equation position & fleqn &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
    quotation style   & german=quotes &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
    citation style    & style=alphabetic &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    bibliography backend & backend=biber &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
    backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
    %
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
    %
    equation position & fleqn &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
    quotation style   & german=quotes &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
    citation style    & style=alphabetic &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    bibliography backend & backend=biber &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
    backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
    %
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
    %
    equation position & fleqn &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
    quotation style   & german=quotes &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
    citation style    & style=alphabetic &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    bibliography backend & backend=biber &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
    backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
    %
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
    %
    equation position & fleqn &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
    quotation style   & german=quotes &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
    citation style    & style=alphabetic &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    bibliography backend & backend=biber &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
    backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
    %
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor} Options in file: \file{preamble/packages.tex} \\
    %
    equation position & fleqn &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:math]{PackagesMath} \\
    quotation style   & german=quotes &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:quotes]{PackagesQuotes} \\
    citation style    & style=alphabetic &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    bibliography backend & backend=biber &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:bibliography]{PackagesCitation} \\
    header and footer & automark,komastyle &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:headfoot]{PackagesHeadFoot} \\
    backlinks in the bibliography & backref=page &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:packages:pdf]{PackagesPDF} \\
    %
  %           \taburowcolors 1{tablesubheadcolor .. tablesubheadcolor}
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor}
    Settings and options in file: \file{preamble/style.tex} \\
    %
    url font        & \cs{urlstyle}\arg{tt} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:text]{StyleText} \\
    threshold for \cs{blockquote} & \cs{SetBlockThreshold}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:quotes]{StyleQuotes} \\
    numbering of figures & \cs{numberwithin}\arg{figure} &
    Section:  \hyperref[sec:style:captions]{StyleCaptions} \\
    paragraph skip or indentation & parskip=false &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:paragraph]{StyleParagraph} \\
    line spacing    & \cs{onehalfspacing} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:linespacing]{StyleLineSpacing} \\
    size of text body   & DIV=11 &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    binding correction  & BCOR=10mm &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    single/two side layout & twoside=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    separate title page & titlepage=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:titlepage]{StyleTitlepage} \\
    sections numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{secnumdepth}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    headings size   & headings=small &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    chapter prefix  & headings=nochapterprefix &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    heading fonts   & \cs{setkomafont}\arg{sectioning} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings:fonts]{StyleHeadingsFonts} \\
    toc numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{tocdepth}\arg{3} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    bibliography in TOC & bibliography=totoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    index in TOC    & index=nottotoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    LOF in TOC  & listof=notoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor}
    Settings and options in file: \file{preamble/style.tex} \\
    %
    url font        & \cs{urlstyle}\arg{tt} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:text]{StyleText} \\
    threshold for \cs{blockquote} & \cs{SetBlockThreshold}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:quotes]{StyleQuotes} \\
    numbering of figures & \cs{numberwithin}\arg{figure} &
    Section:  \hyperref[sec:style:captions]{StyleCaptions} \\
    paragraph skip or indentation & parskip=false &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:paragraph]{StyleParagraph} \\
    line spacing    & \cs{onehalfspacing} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:linespacing]{StyleLineSpacing} \\
    size of text body   & DIV=11 &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    binding correction  & BCOR=10mm &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    single/two side layout & twoside=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    separate title page & titlepage=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:titlepage]{StyleTitlepage} \\
    sections numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{secnumdepth}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    headings size   & headings=small &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    chapter prefix  & headings=nochapterprefix &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    heading fonts   & \cs{setkomafont}\arg{sectioning} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings:fonts]{StyleHeadingsFonts} \\
    toc numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{tocdepth}\arg{3} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    bibliography in TOC & bibliography=totoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    index in TOC    & index=nottotoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    LOF in TOC  & listof=notoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    \SetCell[c=3]{l,bg=tablerowcolor}
    Settings and options in file: \file{preamble/style.tex} \\
    %
    url font        & \cs{urlstyle}\arg{tt} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:text]{StyleText} \\
    threshold for \cs{blockquote} & \cs{SetBlockThreshold}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:quotes]{StyleQuotes} \\
    numbering of figures & \cs{numberwithin}\arg{figure} &
    Section:  \hyperref[sec:style:captions]{StyleCaptions} \\
    paragraph skip or indentation & parskip=false &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:paragraph]{StyleParagraph} \\
    line spacing    & \cs{onehalfspacing} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:linespacing]{StyleLineSpacing} \\
    size of text body   & DIV=11 &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    binding correction  & BCOR=10mm &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    single/two side layout & twoside=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:layout:page]{StylePageLayout} \\
    separate title page & titlepage=true &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:titlepage]{StyleTitlepage} \\
    sections numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{secnumdepth}\arg{2} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    headings size   & headings=small &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    chapter prefix  & headings=nochapterprefix &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings]{StyleHeadings} \\
    heading fonts   & \cs{setkomafont}\arg{sectioning} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:headings:fonts]{StyleHeadingsFonts} \\
    toc numbering depth & \cs{setcounter}\arg{tocdepth}\arg{3} &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    bibliography in TOC & bibliography=totoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    index in TOC    & index=nottotoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    LOF in TOC  & listof=notoc &
    Section: \hyperref[sec:style:toc]{StyleLayoutTOC} \\
    \hline
  \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```